# Lumen 5.6 and sendgrid complete Integration?

Tags: php, lumen

I have a lumen project which needs to be send mails according to some bookings.  Need guidelines for integrating sendgrid with lumen. i am looking at s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: What's wrong with the official Sendgrid docs on Laravel/Lumen? https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/laravel.html

Comment: I tried that but not working. do we really need a laravel sendgrid driver for this integration.

Comment: No, you can just send via SMTP, like that link indicates. Define "not working".

Comment: That document is pretty sparse for Lumen. There is no artisan command make:mail, so I assume it falls apart quickly when you start hacking in your own classes. You'll need a bit more configuration. Here's somewhere to start looking
https://medium.com/@emerico/sending-mail-in-lumen-via-smtp-db8602ed4786